# GPS is going in sleep mode in Android Service

Tags: android, service, gps

I have created a `GPS` service which reads location updates on a regular interval. Earlier there was an issue that `GPS` was going in sleep mode after some time and no location updates were giver thereafter.

Now I have changed my code to unregister and register `GPS` location updates on a regular interval. This solves my problem of `GPS` going in sleep mode but a new issue is created. That is

My service is terminated after some time. I am not able to check the reason for this. Please Help.

Here are some code snipplets

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    timer.schedule(checkLocationListener, new Date(), 1000 * 60 * 15);
}

private TimerTask checkLocationListener = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                lm.removeUpdates(LocationService.this);
  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, CommonConstants.GPS_POLL,
                    CommonConstants.GPS_MIN_DIST, LocationService.this);
            }
        });
    }
};



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(LocationService.class.getSimpleName(), "Start");
    valueMap.put(CommonConstants.STATUS, CommonConstants.STATUS_DROP);
    trackMe();
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    String url = DeviceConfig.getMessage();
                    if (url == null) {
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                        continue;
                    }
                    HttpRequester.getServerResponse(url, null);
                    DeviceConfig.addValue(CommonConstants.SERVER_UPD, "" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                    DeviceConfig.removeMessage();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(LocationService.class.getSimpleName(), "Error", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    return (START_NOT_STICKY);
}

private void trackMe() {
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, CommonConstants.GPS_POLL, CommonConstants.GPS_MIN_DIST,
        this);
    DeviceConfig.addValue(CommonConstants.GPS_STATE, lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        ? CommonConstants.ON : CommonConstants.OFF);
}
```

Comment: Hi pramod, did anything worked for you ???

Comment: I am experiencing this even when Home button is pressed.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont need to register/unregister location update listener again and again, It seems your service stopped, so start your service in sticky mode, in that way, service can be stopped explicitly only.

Comment: Thanks Jitendra,
I have change it to non stickey.
Actually I am very new to Android Development, If you can help me developing my application then I will really appreciate that.

So my first question is:
Is there any reason why my service is getting terminated after some time.

Comment: you need to change it to sticky mode, not in non-sticky mode.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use it like this.    'Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(), getClass());
    PendingIntent pi =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast ( getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, CommonConstants.GPS_POLL, CommonConstants.GPS_MIN_DIST, pi);
)'
Now if location is changed then where I would get updates so that I can handle that

Comment: Again, This method is not working.
Service is not terminated but GPS is going in sleep mode and no updates are received from GPS.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want your service to keep running you need to make it a foreground service (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification))

But why not use this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long, float, android.location.Criteria, android.app.PendingIntent) to start your service each time the location changes?

Phil

Comment: Thanks Philip,
Can you please share an Example for this. Considering i am new to android and this is my first App.

Answer (score 0):

SO far I am doing this.

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
   CommonConstants.GPS_POLL,CommonConstants.GPS_MIN_DIST, pendingIntent);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
   CommonConstants.NW_POLL, CommonConstants.NW_MIN_DIST, pendingIntent);
```

Please suggest if you have some better solution.